# How to show that one series of observations are faster that another series for them same task statisitcally

Tags: probability, paired-data

Hi I have a dataset consisting of two series of observations (times to reach a goal) of users performing a task. Each observation is paired with another one in the other set representing exactly the same task (goal position, start position and subject are the same).

How do I show statistically that one series is quicker than the other and with how much significance.

The data could look like this for example

```
A | B
-----
9 | 8
8 | 8
6 | 7
8 | 7
9 | 9
5 | 4
6 | 5
```

with sum(A)=51 and sum(B)=48

So to rephrase, how do I show that given an element of the series B it is probably smaller than the corresponding one from the series A?

In practice my dataset is larger and in minutes and seconds not integers. I have 165 pairs of data in the real dataset.

Help appreciated

Comment: Do you have any censoring? (Ie observations whose time you only know is longer than some value.)

Comment: Yes, if I understand the term correctly I do. The way the experiment was setup there was a cutof at 5 minutes after which the subject was directed to begin the next task.

I have 24 instances of this in one series  35  in the other one  and 8 where both paired items experienced this